# Why this function is not finding the minimum value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

## Data

I have two vectors that are combined to create a `data.frame`:

```
datax = data.frame(vlead = vlr, vfoll= vr) 



> dput(datax)
    structure(list(vlead = c(18, 18.1, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 18.5, 18.6, 
    18.7, 18.8, 18.9, 19, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 19.4, 19.5, 19.6, 19.7, 
    19.8, 19.9, 20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 20.5, 20.6, 20.7, 20.8, 
    20.9, 21, 21.1, 21.2, 21.3, 21.4, 21.5, 21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 21.9, 
    22, 22.1, 22.2, 22.3, 22.4, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.8, 22.9, 23, 
    23.1, 23.2), vfoll = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)), .Names = c("vlead", 
    "vfoll"), row.names = c(NA, -53L), class = "data.frame")
```

## Function

And following function:

```
s_BX <- function(v,vl){
  1.5 + 0.9*min(v,vl)
}
```

## What I want to do

In the `datax` data frame, I want to create a new column called `BX` that is a result of function `s_BX` for given vlead and vfoll:

```
library(dplyr)
> datax %>% mutate(BX = s_BX(vfoll, vlead))
```

#### But the result is wrong:

```
vlead vfoll   BX
    1   18.0    20 17.7
    2   18.1    20 17.7
    3   18.2    20 17.7
    4   18.3    20 17.7
    5   18.4    20 17.7
    6   18.5    20 17.7
    7   18.6    20 17.7
    8   18.7    20 17.7
    9   18.8    20 17.7
    10  18.9    20 17.7
```

Instead of getting the `minimum` of `vlead` and `vfoll` for a given row, the function is taking the `min` of the whole vectors.

## Question

How can I fix this to get the following expected output?

```
> BX = sapply(vlr, function (x) 1.5+0.9*min(20,x))
> BX
 [1] 17.70 17.79 17.88 17.97 18.06 18.15 18.24 18.33 18.42 18.51 18.60 18.69 18.78 18.87 18.96
[16] 19.05 19.14 19.23 19.32 19.41 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50
[31] 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50
[46] 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50 19.50
```

Comment: Change `min` to `pmin` in your function `s_BX`.

Comment: @Arun Thank you very much for `pmin`!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `rowwise()`:

```
datax %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(BX = s_BX(vfoll, vlead))
```

Comment: I get error: `Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector`

Comment: It works for me with the structure you posted. My version of dplyr is 0.4.1. What's yours?

Comment: I have `dplyr 0.4.3`.  Its giving me error but thanks for your answer. Didn't know about `rowwise`.

Comment: I checked it on `dplyr 0.4.3` and it still works. Are you sure you haven't made any changes to the data structure as you posted it?

Comment: Yes, didn't make any change. I'll try after restarting R.